# PHP null object with non-null object

Tags: php, polymorphism

I've been trying to wrap my head around null objects in PHP.

If I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class A {
    public function test() {
        $test = $this->run( 'test', __FUNCTION__ );
    }

    public function run($callback) {
        if ( 'test' ) == false {
        $null = new A_Null_Object;
        return $null->$callback();
    }
}
```

And then a subclass to use as a null object:

```
class A_Null_Object extends A {
    public function test() {
        return 'Test was invalid';
    }
}
```

Would it not make sense to create a "not null" object/subclass as well, so that $test can be returned without any additional formatting or conditioning in the parent class? (which is the purpose of refactoring the original class in the first place) Or does this defeat the purpose of the null-object in the first place?

I feel like I'm missing something here, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: same function name for A & A_Null_Object. No problem will raise at this situation?

Comment: ` if ( 'test' ) == false ` i think this line contains an error